# 'None' value always returned by scipy.integrate.fixed_quad?

Tags: python, scipy

The function [`scipy.integrate.fixed_quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.fixed_quad.html) returns a `None` with every call:

> Returns:
>
> val : float
>
> Gaussian quadrature approximation to the integral
>
> none : None
>
> Statically returned value of None

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/47bb6febaa10658c72962b9615d5d5aa2513fa3a/scipy/integrate/_quadrature.py#L150) of the function, the `None` is returned always no matter what. What is the meaning of this *Statically returned value of None*? Why is this value always returned?

Comment: I think this is to be interchangeable with other integration functions that return an estimated error. A missing value would cause an `type error` if you unpack the return values or index the first value with `return_value[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of this *Statically returned value of None*?

Looking for `"Statically returned"` in search engine gives docs of mentioned `scipy.integrate.fixed_quad` as first result, so it does not seem to have special formal definition. I would say that is simple information that this function does return `None` not matter input it got, as opposed to function where output depend on input.